# Password Grant to secondary user store

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I configured a secondary user store where I want to store all of my users.

Maybe I missed something because when I try to generate an access token for a user stored in the secondary user store I get an error.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<USR_NAME>&password=<USR_PASSWD>"     -H "Authorization: Basic <BASE64_KEY_SECRET>"   https://localhost:8243/token
```

The error response:

`{"error_description":"Authentication failed for <USER_NAME>@carbon.super","error":"invalid_grant"}`.

If I pass a user of the primary user store it returns the access token.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try this. `username=<USERSTORE_DOMAIN>/<USR_NAME>`

Comment: {"error_description":"Authentication failed for DOMAIN/USER@carbon.super","error":"invalid_grant"}

Comment: can you login to store/publisher with a secondary userstore user?

Comment: No I get an error

Comment: That means the secondary userstore is not configured/deployed properly. Did you see any error in the log while creating it?

Comment: `INFO - UserStoreDeploymentManager Realm configuration of tenant:-1234  modified with /mnt/172.18.0.9/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/userstores/secondaryDomain.xml`

But I can see the secondary user store in the carbon panel and i can also insert users and roles.

Comment: @Bee Maybe I have to modify claims ?

Comment: Maybe your user search base is incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166481/discussion-between-fr4ncx-and-bee).

Comment: have you managed to resolve this? I am facing the same issue..